# How can I json.parse localstorage?

Tags: javascript

Based on the value inside the localStorage **geo__location**, I should show and hide an element on the page.
If the value of the **country** is US I should show the element but hide it if it's not US.

If I run:
window.localStorage.getItem("geo__location")

in console, I get this:

```
"{"country":"US","currency":["USD"]}"
```

But how can I check only the value of **country** inside the json?

Comment: Not meaning to be harsh, but ~3K rep and you couldn't search for a way to parse JSON in JavaScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: You already mentioned “json.parse” in the title, which is the incorrect capitalization of the `JSON.parse` method. You’re aware of this method, so why not simply use it here?

Comment: If you know what `JSON.parse` is, then you would apply it, and not ask a question about how to use something you already know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer to your question is in the header of same.
localStorage only stores strings, so before putting values into localStorage use `JSON.stringify()`, and to read them use `JSON.parse()`

```js
JSON.parse('{"country":"US","currency":["USD"]}').country
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON.parse. Here goes an example.

```js
var obj = JSON.parse('{"country":"US","currency":["USD"]}');
console.log(obj['country']);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('geo__location')).country
```

You don't need to add `window` at the beginning. You parse the JSON first and then exrtact the property

Answer (score 1):

Using `JSON.parse`:

```js
const item = JSON.parse( window.localStorage.getItem("geo__location"))
item.country;
item.currency
```